# PBKDF2 with SHA256 on android

Tags: android, encryption, sha256, pbkdf2

I want to generate a derived hash of a password using PBKDF2 with SHA256. with this `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")` this work but it use SHA1.
With `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256")` (or `SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256","SC")` when with spongycastle) i have an error.

How can i succeed to generate a hash using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you use version 1.47 or higher of SpongyCastle, you can invoke PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 directly:

```
PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());
generator.init(PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS5PasswordToUTF8Bytes(password), salt, iterations);
KeyParameter key = (KeyParameter)generator.generateDerivedMacParameters(keySizeInBits);
```

In versions of BC < 1.47, you could not specify SHA256 digest and it defaulted to SHA1.

Comment: Yup, works. Android itself won't handle AES256  cryptography, so you need the above. The byte[] you get using "key.getKey()" and importing Spongy Castle is easy as adding the following into your dependencies in your build.gradle: compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.54.0.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.54.0.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pg:1.54.0.0'

Comment: `compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.54.0.0'` is enough, you don't need the extra dependencies listed by @MacD

Answer (score 2):

Bouncy Castle doesn't support `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256` so this won't work. You can try implementing it yourself. Look at the source of `PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator.java` and replace `SHA1Digest` with `SHA256Digest`.

Comment: Do you know if there is any existing library compatible with Android which have this implementation ?

Comment: Haven't heard of any. Pretty much anything should be compatible though, since this doesn't really do anything platform-specific.